# Progress Bar Smooth Fill in a Logo (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have a page that asks users for information to fill out a form.  When they submit, I take them to a screen that says "Calculating your results...".

I want a progress bar that fluidly loads from 0-100% in 10 or so seconds.  The kicker is that I want the progress bar to be a grayed out version of my logo (the logo is purely text, but non-web text) that's slowly filled with color like a progress bar, to 100%.

Is there any way to do this in jQuery?  Or do I have to make something in Flash?

Thanks!

Comment: i think this could help http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the new `<progress></progress>` tag(s) and use CSS to place your logo in the background. Here is a quick overview of styling it in Firefox, and I'm sure there is more information out there now since this is over a year old:

http://blog.oldworld.fr/index.php?post/2011/07/The-HTML5-progress-element-in-Firefox